# Latex error while using algorithm

Tags: errors, algorithms, algorithmicx

I get the following error while compiling the algorithm using winedt and miktex:

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.42 \end{algorithmic}
```

Here is my source code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\textheight=9.75in
\textwidth 6.55in
\hoffset=-.75in
\voffset=-.5in
\headsep=-.25in

\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algc}
\usepackage{algcompatible}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}

\algnewcommand{\LINECOMMENT}[1]{\STATE\(\triangleright\) #1}


\begin{document}

\floatname{algorithm}{Algorithm}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Cuckoo Search Algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\REQUIRE{A set $N = \{1,2,\ldots, n\}$ of $n$ jobs, a set $M = \{1,2,\ldots ,m\}$ of $m$ identical parallel machines, processing time $p_i$ for each job $i \in N$, MaxGeneration, and stopping criterion.}
\STATE Generate an initial population of $R$ host nests $x_i$, $(i=1,\ldots ,R)$.
\WHILE{$t < $ MaxGeneration or stopping criterion}
  \STATE Obtain a cuckoo randomly by Levy flights.
  \STATE Evaluate its quality/fitness $F_{i}$.
  \STATE Choose a nest (say, $j$) randomly from the population of $R$ and compute its quality/fitness as $F_{j}$.
   \IF {$F_{i}> F_{j}$,}
    \STATE Replace $j$ with the new solution.
    % \ELSE
     \ENDIF
    \STATE A fraction $(P_a)$ of worst nests from the population are abandoned and new ones are constructed.
    \STATE Retain the best quality solutions (or nests with quality solutions).
    \STATE Sort the solutions and find the current best.
\ENDWHILE
\ENSURE{The current best schedule of $n$ jobs and its corresponding MS.}
\end{algorithmic}
\label{CSA}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is due to the fact that you're using "compatible" mode for `algorithmicx` but you're loading last the package `algpseudocode`.

You have to load *only* the package `algcompatible`, that is, use

```
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algcompatible}
```

instead of

```
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algc}
\usepackage{algcompatible}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
```

Comment: Thanks.  It worked.  However, it worked last week the way I had it.  This is strange.

Comment: @JatinderGupta Happy that it worked. Remember that you can [accept the answer](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852) if it solved your problem :-)

Comment: Thanks.  I have learned to accept an answer and I did that now.

Comment: @JatinderGupta Are you sure?